# Can JVM bytecode be manipulated at compile time?

Tags: java, compilation, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Is it possible to use a bytecode manipulation library like ASM at compile time?

Specifically, I'd like to use Java's annotation processing API to implement boilerplate-heavy methods on annotated classes. Implementing an [annotation processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html) is straightforward enough, but it seems like the `.class` files don't yet exist when the `Processor` is run. Is there another way?

Comment: See: http://techbitsfromsridhar.blogspot.ca/2013/02/java-compiler-plug-ins-in-java-8-use.html

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in Javassist ( http://www.jboss.org/javassist ) which can enhance and save classes as a post-compilation step.

This article describes how to save enhanced classes : https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-build-time

in particular, once you have altered a class, you can do something like this:

```
 compiledClass.writeFile("/tmp/modifiedClassesFolder");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? This article explains JBoss very well, but it's using `Ant`, could you please provide a Gradle example?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible since the following project is doing it: [Project Lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok)

Also:

Java 8 will bring a new mechanism that allows you to write plug-ins for the Java compiler (javac). A compiler plug-in lets you add new phases to javac without making changes to its code base. New behavior can be encapsulated in a plug-in and distributed for other people to use. For example, javac plug-ins could be used to do the following:

• Add extra compile-time checks

• Add code transformations

• Perform customized analysis of source code

Answer (score -1):

You should use CGLib instead. With CGLib you can add proxies with method interceptors and have the interceptor implement your boilerplate code. Another option is to look at Javassist. With Javassist you literally create a new subclass using actual text (in strings) and have javassist compile it into byte-code.

Comment: @bmargulies Yes they work at runtime, but as they manipulate byte arrays the could be used as post compilation steps to override existing .class files